# JQuery $.when multiple $.ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have code like this

*prod is input data*

```
function moduledep(prod){
        $.when(
            $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : 'getRps',
            data : {prod : prod.value},
            dataType: "JSON"
            })
        ).done(function(a) {
                console.log(a[0].moduleid);
        });
    }
```

But when I change the code like this, it sends a message error unidentified

[image]

error:
[image]

What's wrong? 
Thank You, Regards

Comment: on which line you get error?

Comment: go with http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: console.log(a[0].moduleid); and console.log(b[0].moduleid);
there's 2 unidentified,,
am I wrong about multiple $.ajax inside $.when?

Comment: Are you running this in console?

Comment: So, isn't it likely that one of the ajax calls is not returning an object with a `.moduleid` property?

Comment: Yes, my code refer to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/
but it's result unidentified

Comment: Try `console.log(a); console.log(b)` and see what you get.

Comment: @artm - or even better, set a breakpoint and look at both `a` and `b`.  I'm constantly amazed how few people seem to understand how the use the debugger when it's a huge time saver.

Comment: Vishwanath :: yes, it's just check, just more simple checking
jfriend00 :: It's return obj json

Comment: artm :: It's lok like this
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-cN_LgYxRdvw/VL82_E44FII/AAAAAAAAAC4/N9tgaQ-CGbA/h120/c.PNG

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first version is working and second is not working then `a` and `b` are arrays so you need to use

```
console.log(a[0][0].moduleid);
console.log(b[0][0].moduleid);
```

because the parameter structure passed to `done` callback changes if there are more than 1 promise passed to `$.when`.

If there are more than 1 promise passed to `$.when` then the parameter set of each of the promise callback will be passed as an array to the done callback in the same order. So in your case since you are using ajax promise `a` & `b` will be arrays containing 3 values each, they are the ajax data, ajax status and the jqXhr object.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tsrqaam9/) - check the console to see the difference in structure